# When doing a GET request in MongoDB, it show only " [] ", Why?

Tags: database, mongodb

//server.js file code

```
const express = require("express");const mongoose = require("mongoose");const app = express();const BusModel = require("./models/Bus");
```

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://das:dasismass@cluster0.j7nrcsd.mongodb.net/taskbusinfo?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
```

```
app.get("/getInfo", async (req, res) => {try {const data = await BusModel.find({});res.send(data);} catch (err) {console.log(err);}});
```

```
app.listen(8000, () => {console.log("Server listening");});
```

//Bus.js schema code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

```
const BusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({busnum:{type: Number,required: true},departure:{type: String,required: true},arrival:{type: String,required: true}});
```

```
const BusModel = mongoose.model("businfo",BusSchema);
```

```
module.exports = BusModel;
```

[image: DB image]

[image: Get Request image]

Tried connecting in old ways, when I did that it didn't connect to DB.
I don't know if there's any error in code, I'm doing MongoDB for first time.

Comment: add `await` to `mongoose.connect(...`, or you can follow this link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: When adding `await` to `mongoose.connect(...` it show " Connection was refused by the server. "

Comment: now we found the issue, did you already added your ip address to Atlas? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/

Comment: Yes, I've added my IP address.

Comment: then please re-check your username and password, you actually successfully ping the server.

Comment: anyway, never share your credential, just use an example. ex: `mongodb+srv://test:test@test/taskbusinfo?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. i suggest to create a new user and remove that one.

Comment: Let me check, thanks